# How to calculate totals of two subgroups using Java 8 Streams with maps and lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Car` POJO:

```
class Car
{
  String make;
  int year;
  BigDecimal amount;
}
```

And a `List<Car>` of cars such as that:

```
make  : year : price
honda : 2011 : $20,000
honda : 2011 : $30,000
honda : 2012 : $50,000
ford  : 2012 : $12,000
```

Where I want to have as a result:

```
// Map<make, List<year, totalForYear>>
Map<String, Map<int, BigDecimal>> revenuesByMakeAndYear;
```

How can I achieve this with Streams? So far I'm halfway with:

```
// Map<make, List<car>>
Map<String, List<Car>> carsByMake = cars.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            car -> car.getMake(),
            car -> cars.stream()
                .filter(subCar -> subCar.getMake().equals(car.getMake())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

But how do I get to the next step?

Comment: `List<year, totalForYear>`? Do you mean `Map<year, totalForYear>` (or actually `Map<Integer,BigDecimal>`)?

Comment: `List<year, totalForYear>`: what does that mean? List has a single generic type.

Comment: I believe the bigger issue is that you are trying to create a List with 2 type parameters `Map<make, List<year, totalForYear>>`, and that is not possible.

Comment: Yes I fixed that. I did it otherwise to make show what values I meant rather than the actual type to make it easier to read.

Comment: And my apologies, I mean Map of Map. The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to create the second map, I'm stuck at having a list still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use nested `groupingBy` to group by make and year, and then `reducing` to produce the total revenue):

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,BigDecimal>> totals = 
    cars.stream ()
        .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (c->c.make,
                                         Collectors.groupingBy (c->c.year,
                                                                Collectors.reducing (new BigDecimal(0),
                                                                                     c->c.amount,
                                                                                     BigDecimal::add))));
```

If the property you wish to sum wasn't a `BigDecimal`, you could have replaced `reducing` with the simpler `summingInt` or `summingLong` or `summingDouble`.

Of course, assuming your `Car` class has getters, you should replace `c->c.make` with `Car::getMake`, etc...

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,BigDecimal>> totals = 
    cars.stream ()
        .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (Car::getMake,
                                         Collectors.groupingBy (Car::getYear,
                                                                Collectors.reducing (new BigDecimal(0),
                                                                                     Car::getAmount,
                                                                                     BigDecimal::add))));
```

I ran this on your sample input and got:

```
{honda={2011=50000, 2012=50000}, ford={2012=12000}}
```

Comment: The second groupingBy gives me a compiler error in that it doesn't now the type is Car (that is I can't call getYear (assuming getters and setters)

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I had a typo of `Car:getAmount` instead of `Car::getAmount`. perhaps that was the issue. Fixed now, and passes compilation for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupingBy` with `Map` and specify what to do with duplicate keys (i.e. add the `amount` to generate aggregate result). Try the following:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(); //Your list
Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>> sum = cars.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getMake(), 
                Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getYear(), c -> c.getAmount(), 
                        (c1, c2) -> c1.add(c2))));
```

Comment: I'm getting the same compiler error with the getYear where the compiler doesn't know the type is car

Comment: I compiled the above snippet before posting here (and it worked fine) maybe try changing it to `Car::getYear`?